# How to use Persian variable in MathJax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

I want to show a Persian variable, but it is displayed as individual letters `س ر م ا ی ه` instead of `سرمایه`. Can someone solve this?

Here's my code:

```js
function createFormula() {
  var value = '`a*b/(5+9)-6+8/9+9+"سرمایه"/895+9+' + '"' + 'c' + '"' + '`';
  document.querySelector('#formula').textContent = value;
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'formula']);
}

//show س ر م ا ی ه  insted سرمایه
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="show text" onclick="createFormula()">
<br>
<span id="formula" style></span>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e30ugtxq/11/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the text to display properly by making two changes:

- Wrap the Persian text in `\text{...}`.
- Set the [option](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html) `mtextFontInherit` to `true`, to [prevent MathJax's font from being used](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/HTML-CSS.html).

```js
function createFormula() {
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        "HTML-CSS": { mtextFontInherit: true }
    });
     
    var value='`a*b/(5+9)-6+8/9+9+\\text{'+
   'سرمایه'
   +'}/895+9+'+'"'+'c'+'"'+'`';
    document.querySelector('#formula').textContent =value;
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,'formula']); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="show text" onclick="createFormula()">
<br>
<span id="formula" style></span>
```

Comment: Another note - I moved the Persian text to its own line in JavaScript to make it easier to edit because most code editors have poor bi-directional support. It doesn't change the result.

Comment: @lindrev - Sure! By the way, I tested again, and looks like `mtextFontInherit` is enough. `\text{}` isn't needed.

Comment: @Kobi the config sets `mtextfontinherit` for the HTML-CSS output but then uses a combined configuration file which will load the CommonHTML output, so this setting has no effect until a user switches to HTML-CSS output.  Anyway, the relevant issue is https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/474.  Some browsers do not properly combine characters across spans in which case \text will help.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger - `mtextFontInherit` may be a workaround, but I think it is required in this case - the result is that just a single `span` is created instead of multiple `span`s (for each letter).

Comment: Not quite. mtextfontinherit specifies that MathJax will not use its own fonts for content in mtext elements (but leaves it to CSS). However, the relevant Persian Unicode characters are not covered by MathJax's fonts anyway so the same thing happens for such content via MathJax's font fallback behavior, https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html.

Comment: I have another question,how can i set satck to mathjax and show my formula ?

Comment: Hey @lindrev - It would work best if you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with new example code. I don't even know what `satck` is.

Comment: thanks,i ask a new question   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160323/how-to-set-stack-to-mathjax