# how to set stack to mathjax?

Tags: jquery, mathjax

i want set expresion of stack to mathjax (dynamically)

this is my stack

```
var showStack=[];
showStack.push({
                Key: 'topic',
                Value:"سرمایه"
            });
showStack.push({
                Key: 'operator',
                Value: "+"
            });            
showStack.push({
                Key: 'topic',
                Value: "مالیات"
            });          
showStack.push({
                Key: 'opeator',
                Value: "/"
            });
showStack.push({
                Key: 'number',
                Value: "8569"
            });            
showStack.push({
                Key: 'opeator',
                Value: "-"
            });      
showStack.push({
                Key: 'topic',
                Value: "اندوخته قانونی - سال قبل"
            });
```

and this code create my fomula from my stack

```
  jQuery.each( showStack, function( i, val ) {
  if(val.Key=='topic'){
    text+='`\\text{'+ val.Value+'}`';
  }
  else
    text+=val.Value;
});
```

createFormula for create mathjax formula

```
 function createFormula() {
  var text="";
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "HTML-CSS": { mtextFontInherit: true }
});


  document.querySelector('#formula').textContent =text;
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,'formula']);      
 }
```

but result is

```
سرمایه+مالیات/8569-اندوخته قانونی - سال قبل
```

my code not work,Where is my problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change this code

```
 var text="";
jQuery.each( showStack, function( i, val ) {
  if(val.Key=='topic'){
    text+='\\text{'+ val.Value+'}'; // remove `
  }
  else
    text+=val.Value;
});
```

And add this code

```
var value='`'+text+'`';

 document.querySelector('#formula').textContent =value;
 MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,'formula']);
```